# Get type of property in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

I have method:

```
static T RandomObject<T> (...) {
var tmp = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
...
   foreach (PropertyInfo info in tmp.GetType().GetProperties()){
   ...
   }
}
```

And if class T have object properties I want to generate them random too, so what I do is:

```
var t = info.PropertyType;
obj = RandomObject<t>(...);
```

And then I get:

> The type or namespace name t could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: That syntax for generic instantiation requires the type to be known at compile time.  You'd need to use some form of reflection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172334.aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173128.aspx

Comment: Reflection is an advanced topic which you should leave to experienced programmers.  Pick something simpler to play with while learning the language.

Comment: Well, thanks Mike but I have to do this :)

Comment: why are you assuming it has an empty constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
obj = GetType().GetMethod("RandomObject", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, ...);
```

Comment: RandomObject<T>(double, double, int, int)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'.

Comment: RandomObject is not a type it's a method. this will not work. you need to construct a generic method with reflection and Invoke it.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I read it as a type.  Updated the answer.